# php how to generate a string use letter and number?

Tags: php

I want generate a string like 'A00021' ,the number of length is five ,when the number is biger than 10000 then the string like 'B00001',how to generate string like this?

Comment: `10000` is five characters so is `99999`. Do you mean when the length is greater than 5 increase by 1 alpha character? Question is very vague as it currently stands.

Answer (score 0):

It might help you...

```
$str = "A10000";
if(substr($str,-5) >= '10000'){
    $newstr = strtoupper(chr(ord(substr($str,0,1)) + 1))."00001";
}else{
    $newstr = substr($str,0,1).substr("00000".(substr($str,-5)+1),-5);
}
echo $newstr;
```